# Possible? A predicate function asserting arg is non-null (as well as some other property)

Tags: typescript

I often find myself writing predicates that, for convenience, accept either the value I am testing or null (returning false for null). e.g.

```
function isBlobby(s: Shape|null): boolean {
  return s != null && ...
}
```

Say x is known to have type `Shape|null`, it would be nice to be able to write

```
if (isBlobby(x)) {
  doSomethingWith(x.color) // No need for x!.color
}
```

If I give `is Shape` as the return type of `isBlobby`, this works, but goes awry if I add an `else` - the type checker assumes x is null in the else part.

Of course this makes sense - the `is` syntax is for type predicates, not general predicates, but I was wondering if there is any way to make something like this work?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try `function isBlobby(s: Shape|unknown): isShape`

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's the problem with type guard `is`?

Comment: You could have separate guard for `null` and then separate for `Shape` (e.g. `const isDefined = <T>(s: T|null): s is T => s != null)`

Comment: @captain-yossarian what is `isShape` here?

Comment: @AlekseyL. true, or I could just add `x != null && ...` to the test, but the goal was to have the convenience that `isBlobby` already handles that. It's not a big problem, just curious if there was a solution.

Comment: Maybe worth filing an issue/feature request on TypeScript's github.